# 3d function surface parameter entry

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to follow a tutorial that involves using a 3d function surface, but in the tutorial, the location of the text entry field seems to have changed in the recent 2.8 update.

https://youtu.be/DqBOva04lcE?t=336

where can I locate the entry field shown in this video now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add your math function mesh, on the bottom left of the 3D view you will see the operator editor (circled in middle image). Open it to view the various parameters of the operator you last executed, including the add math function mesh.

[image]

Comment: after I click off of the object, the editor disappears, how do I get it back?

Comment: @Melvin the XYZ Math Surface tool is an operator, and it does not generate an editable, parametric object but rather a finished mesh. After it is executed the parameters are available to you in the popping panel to change and play with, until you perform another operation (such as deselecting or transforming). Then, the history panel will now represent a different (latest) operator's parameters.